# Clustered Server: One User Exist Only in Server 2

Tags: ibm-domino

Good day.

Currently, we do have two (2) Domino servers that are clustered. All .nsf files are replicating with each other. I wanted to test if external email would pass through the server. I think if I can create a user that only exists on Server 2 I will be avail to test the clustered server or for experimentation purposes.

Is this possible since they both are replicating? Can I exempt one user not to replicate with the clustered server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Torsten said is not totally correct. You can setup the CA process and a user creation policy so THAT there will be an automatically creation from a mailfile on the server you specify (e.g. done via adminp). So it might be possible that, depending what you does and how your environment is setup, created indeed automatically the mailfile.

I would create two users (user 1 and user 2) without mailfile, then create the mailfile per hand. User 1 should point to the mailfile1 on server 1 and user 2 should point to the mailfile 2 on the server 2. That should allow you to test that construct.

Comment: I would try your suggestion Sir BastianW. I will contact immediately soon after this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "automatism" that lets every database on one clusterpartner have a replica on the other one. If you set the mail- home- server of the "testuser" to Server2 and delete the replica of the mailfile on the other server, then it will not be automatically recreated, and all mail has to go through Server2 to reach this user.

Comment: In my case when I delete "testuser" in Server 2 it also deletes in Server 1.

Comment: NO. You don't delete the USER. You delete his mailfile... This is a difference...